# How do I open each link on a webview to chrome custom tab?

Tags: java, android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I would like to open each link on webview to chrome custom tabs when the link is clicked or tabbed.

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl(uri);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(uri)){
                webView.loadUrl(uri);
            }else{
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                builder.build().launchUrl(MainActivity.this, uri);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have to redirect your URL in external web browser like

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("http")) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    });
```